# For any local search algorithm, could one step of searching in neighborhoods can always be done in a polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, local, computation-theory

Since finding a locally optimal solution is presumably easier than finding an optimal solution, can we claim that for any local search algorithm, one step of searching in neighborhoods can always be done in polynomial time?

Answer (score 1):

No. How easy it is to search a neighborhood depends on how the neighborhood is defined.

Imagine the **Max-2SAT** problem: 
Let *U* be a set of binary variables *x_1 , ..., x_n* and let *C* be a set of clauses
*c* over *U* . The number of literals in each clause is at most two and the weight *w(c)* of a clause *c ∈ C* is a positive integer. A solution is an assignment of *x_1 , ..., x_n* . A clause is satisfied, if at least one variable is 1.
The aim is to find an assignment, that maximizes the sum of the weights of the satisfied clauses.

Let **FLIP** be the neighborhood structure in which a neighbor *r* of a solution *s* is obtained by flipping one bit *x_i* of *s*.
This neighborhood has polynomial size and the next best neighbor can be found in polynomial time.

Let **ALL** be the neighborhood structure which contains all possible solutions of *U*. This neighborhood has exponential size and it takes exponential time to find the next best neighbor (which is in this case the global optimum).
The local search algorithm then terminates after one step, so it is not really a good local search algorithm, but one with an exponential neighborhood function.

There are more complex algorithms with an exponential neighborhood function, for example in “Local search with an exponential neighborhood for the servers load balancing problem” by I.A. Davydov, P.A. Kononova, Yu.A. Kochetov, 2014.
They search for the next neighbor with a mixed integer program in the set of all possible subsets of disks on all servers, which are exponential many possible neighbors.

If you have a local search problem for which you can produce some solution in polynomial time, calculate the cost of a solution in polynomial time and find the best neighbor in polynomial time, your problem lies within the complexity class PLS (See “How Easy Is Local Search?” by David S Johnson, Christos H Papadimitriou, and Mihalis Yannakakis, 1988).